# How to show custom HTML element in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5

We are upgrading a legacy system that uses CKEditor4 to CKEditor5. In one of the editor's content, it contains something like this:

```
<whatsapp>
This is pretext for whatsapp
</whatsapp>
```

We would like to show the entire content, including the `<whatsapp>` and `</whatsapp>` in the editor body.

This works fine in CKEditor4 but is displayed as blank in CKEditor5.

The CKEditor5 config used is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #container {
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
            .ck-editor__editable[role="textbox"] {
                /* editing area */
                min-height: 200px;
            }
            .ck-content .image {
                /* block images */
                max-width: 80%;
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="editor">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/36.0.1/super-build/ckeditor.js"></script>

        <script>
            CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor.create(document.getElementById("editor"), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'sourceEditing'
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                },

                htmlSupport: {
                    allow: [
                        {
                            name: /.*/,
                            attributes: true,
                            classes: true,
                            styles: true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                removePlugins: [
                    'CKBox',
                    'CKFinder',
                    'EasyImage',
                    'RealTimeCollaborativeComments',
                    'RealTimeCollaborativeTrackChanges',
                    'RealTimeCollaborativeRevisionHistory',
                    'PresenceList',
                    'Comments',
                    'TrackChanges',
                    'TrackChangesData',
                    'RevisionHistory',
                    'Pagination',
                    'WProofreader',
                    'MathType'
                ]
            }).then(editor => {
                    let mydata = '<div>hello world</div><whatsapp>hi whatsapp</whatsapp><wechat>hey wechat</wechat><div>bye world</div>';
                     editor.setData(mydata)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two ways to achieve this.

1. Creates the upcast and downcast conversion via Plugin
2. Uses the [general HTML support](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/general-html-support.html)

To create custom plugin, you will need to build the editor via the `npm` and `webpack`. Below shows a very simple example how this can be achieved

```js
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';

class WhatsappPlugin extends Plugin {
    static elementName = 'whatsapp';

    init() {
        registerSchemaAndConversion(this.editor, WhatsappPlugin.elementName);
    }
}

function registerSchemaAndConversion(editor, elementName) {
    if (!editor.model.schema.isRegistered(elementName)) {
        editor.model.schema.register(elementName, {
            inheritAllFrom: '$block',
        });
    }

    editor.conversion.for('downcast').elementToElement({
        model: elementName,
        view: elementName,
    });

    editor.conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
        view: {
            name: elementName,
        },
        model: elementName,
        converterPriority: 'low',
    });
}

class Editor extends ClassicEditor {}

Editor.defaultConfig = {
    plugins: [WhatsappPlugin, ...Editor.builtinPlugins],
}

export default Editor;
```